# Software implementation of Gardner Loop

Tags: digital-communications, python, interpolation, demodulation, constellation-diagram

My objective is to create a Gardner loop to remove the timing offset present in my signal. To achieve best timing SNR, I downsample my signal to 2 samples per symbol. It is depicted below:

[image: downsampled signal]

where blue and red vertical lines indicate the symbol and the sample duration respectively.

Next, I plug my signal into Gardner loop, here is my code:

```
def Gardner_loop(time_support, sig):
    
    # Initialization of the parameters
    sample_rate = 1/time_support[1]
    sps = int(sample_rate/f_symb) # samples per symbol
    sig_n_1 = int(np.ceil(sps/2)) # x(n-1)
    sig_n_2 = int(sps) # x(n-2)   
    loop_filter = f_symb//20 # BW of the loop filter
    loop_num = 100
    error_symbol = np.zeros(loop_num)
    
    error_list = []
    sig_wo_time_err = []
    step = sps
    
    # Gardner loop
    for i in range(1, loop_num):
        # Calculate the error
        error_symbol[i] = sig.real[sig_n_1 + step + int(error_symbol[i-1]*loop_filter)]\
        *(sig.real[sig_n_2 + step + int(error_symbol[i-1]*loop_filter)]\
        - sig.real[step+int(error_symbol[i-1]*loop_filter)])\
        
        + sig.imag[sig_n_1 + step + int(error_symbol[i-1]*loop_filter)]\
        *(sig.imag[sig_n_2 + step + int(error_symbol[i-1]*loop_filter)]\
        - sig.imag[step+int(error_symbol[i-1]*loop_filter)]) 
        
        # Make a step
        step+=sps

        # Save the error
        error_list.append(error_symbol[i])
        
        # Save the signal with reduced error
        sig_wo_time_err.append(sig.real[sig_n_2+step+int(error_symbol[i-1]*loop_filter)] \
        + 1j*sig.imag[sig_n_2+step+int(error_symbol[i-1]*loop_filter)])
    
    error_to_plot = np.array(error_symbol)
    # Plotting
    plt.plot(np.arange(1, loop_num+1), error_to_plot)
    plt.xlabel('loop number')
    plt.ylabel('error')
    return np.array(sig_wo_time_err)
```

the plot of the error is represented in the figure below:

[image: error from Gardner]

the constellation looks like this:

[image: constellation]

indicating that there is still the timing error.

*My first specific question is*: can somebody check if my implementation of Gardner loop is correct? Because I am not sure if the code I wrote does what is needed and I cannot find any software implementation of Gardner loop in internet.

In addition to that, I know that I need to interpolate the signal at specific points. These points are indicated by the error from Gardner loop. My understanding of the process in the following (see first figure): if the error is positive, then the sampling is too late and the interpolation must happen between 0 and the red line (sample duration). For negative error, interpolation happens at the last sample of the symbol (between red and blue lines). Then we use this interpolated point for further processing inside the loop and eventually drive the error to 0.

To implement this, in the code mentioned above, inside the `for` loop I use the function `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` to get the value of the signal at the time instant indicated by the error. However, with an interpolation length consisting of two points (0 and red line), I receive an error and cannot get the point in between (if needed, I can post my code as well).

*So the last question is* how do I implement the interpolation inside the Gardner loop.

Thank you!

Update:

The eye diagram of the signal before matched filtering and upsampling is depicted below:

[image: eye-diagram of signal]

The eye diagram after matched filtering (MF)

[image: eye-diag after MF]

After interpolation (upsampling with `symbol_rate * 5`) and without MF, the eye-diagram looks like this:

[image: eye upsampled]

After upsampling `symbol_rate*5` and MF:

[image: after MF and upsampling eye diag]

Comment: Could you please post the eye diagram of the received signal after the matched filter? Your signal (first plot in the question) does not look correct to me. Also: don't use only two samples to interpolate! You need to use at least 10-20 samples.

Comment: I didn't read all this in detail yet but to pass along quickly the interpolation is typically done with polyphase filters as with that approach you never actually need to increase the sampling rate and it is all done at 2 samples per symbol. I summarize this in more detail at this post if you haven't come across this yet: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/73645/design-a-timing-recovery-algorithm-with-predefined-samples-with-max-amplitude/73647#73647

Comment: In particular this post which shows how it all fits together including the polyphase resampling for timing adjustment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/51810/symbol-timing-synchronization-using-a-high-sampling-rate/51812#51812

Comment: @MBaz thanks for the reply! I have uploaded eye diagrams. What do you think?

Comment: @DanBoschen thank you for the hint! With polyphase filter interpolation becomes much more intuitive! I will try to incorporate it to the Gardner loop now

Comment: @Python So, this is a 4-PAM signal right? I'm not sure Gardner works for anything but BPSK and QPSK (I have only implemented it for QPSK myself).

Comment: @MBaz no, this is actually QPSK

Comment: @Python That's not the eye diagram of a QPSK signal. You're doing something wrong. If you draw the eye diagram of the I portion of the QPSK signal, you should see the signal taking two values when the eye is open.

Comment: @MBaz I am little confused with your first comment, when you say that we have to use 10-20 samples for interpolation. I thought that the whole point of downsampling the signal to 2 samples/symbol was to ensure that there is a sample at the time calculated by Gardner. When we take 20 samples = 20/2 = 10 symbols, then how do we know where to interpolate?

Comment: @MBaz OK, then I will try to fix my eye-diagram now

Comment: @DanBoschen I am not sure how to implement the coefficients for FIR filters, but I found the function in python: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample_poly.html that resamples automatically. However, there are no coefficients. Would it still ensure the sampling at correct instances in the loop?

Comment: I'm confused by your confusion :) so let me rephrase. You have samples $x(nT_s)$ of a signal $x(t)$. You want to interpolate the signal value at an arbitrary time $x(t_0)$. The interpolation process requires, in theory, _all_ samples; in practice, you will need a few samples before $t_0$ and a few samples after. If you take too few samples, the interpolation will be inaccurate.

Comment: @MBaz OK, but as far as I am concerned, out of these few samples before t_0 and after, we take only one that has the smallest timing error. Then we use this sample as a reference, so the error of the following symbol is calculated from that "reference sample". But how do we compute this "reference sample"?